# Rails 4 "undefined method `image_changed?' for #" on edit with carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, undefined, carrierwave, edit

I have this rails app with "Diys" which have "Steps" assigned to them, those "Steps" have images("add_images_to_steps") assigned to them by carriervawe.
Creating new "Diys" works fine, and showing them too, but when i try to edit them i get

> undefined method `image_changed?' for #Diy:0xb8a1d20

after submitting the form, even if i don't include "add_images_to_steps" fields in the form.

**diys_controller.rb**

```
def edit
  @diy = Diy.find(params[:id])
  @diy.steps.all
  @diy.add_images_to_steps.all
end
...
def update
   respond_to do |format|
     if @diy.update(diy_params)
       format.html { redirect_to @diy, notice: 'Diy was successfully updated.' }
       format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @diy }
     else
       format.html { render :edit }
       format.json { render json: @diy.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
   end
 end
 ...
 private
 def diy_params
    params.require(:diy).permit(:title, :summary, :tip, :warning, steps_attributes: [:step_content, add_images_to_steps_attributes: [:image]])
 end
```

**diys/edit.html.erb**

```
<h1>Editing Diy</h1>

<%= form_for(@diy, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
  <% if @diy.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@diy.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this diy from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @diy.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div id="form_div">
    <%= f.label :title  %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %><br>  
    <%= f.label :summary  %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :summary %><br>
    <%= f.label "Tips"  %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :tip %><br>
    <%= f.label "Warnings"  %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :warning %><br>
      <%= f.fields_for :steps do |step_fields| %>
        <%= step_fields.text_area :step_content %><br>
      <% end %>
    <%= f.submit %>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to 'Show', @diy %> |
  <%= link_to 'Back', diys_path %>
```

**models/diy.rb**

```
class Diy < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :vehicles

    has_many :steps, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :steps, reject_if: :all_blank

    has_many :add_images_to_steps, :through => :steps, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :add_images_to_steps, reject_if: :all_blank
    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

    searchable do
        text :title, :default_boost => 2
        text :summary
        text :tip, :default_boost => 0.5
        text :warning, :default_boost => 0.4
        text :steps do
            steps.map(&:step_content)
        end
    end
end
```

**models/step.rb**

```
class Step < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :diy

    has_many :add_images_to_steps, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :add_images_to_steps, reject_if: :all_blank
    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

**models/add_images_to_step.rb**

```
class AddImagesToStep < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :step
    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

Comment: if you edit image add to require params `:id` like `add_images_to_steps_attributes: [:id, :image]`

Comment: Thank you for your help! This didn't solve my problem which was caused by redundant "mount_uploader..." lines in steps and diys model. But did help with next problem I faced :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, how stupid mistake.

> mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

line in diys and steps models was useless and caused this error.

Also had to make new params for update action to change images properly, with old params it just added new image without deleting old one

```
    def diy_params_update
       params.require(:diy).permit(:id, :title, :summary, :tip, :warning, steps_attributes: [:diy_id, :id, :step_content, add_images_to_steps_attributes: [:step_id, :id, :image]])
    end
```